# matrix multiplication is strange in numpy(m*m equals m.dot(m)!!!)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I find a strange problem in numpy:
if m is a matrix, the results of m1*m2 is always the same as m1.dot(m2)!!!
So how can I multipy two matrixes by elements?(such as m1.*m2 in matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by-design. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

> For `matrix`, **'*' means matrix multiplication**, and the `multiply()` function is used for element-wise multiplication.

e.g.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.multiply([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]])
array([[ 5, 12],
       [21, 32]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply matrices (of type `numpy.matrix`), NumPy assumes you want [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), which doesn't really seem that strange to me.  To multiply element-wise, either use arrays (`numpy.array`) instead of matrices, or use `numpy.multiply()`.